# How would I define 'Ace' in a blackjack deck as 11 or 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to create a blackjack game. The only issue I have is how to change Ace to be 1 if 11 will bust the hand.

I have tried to use scores.append(Ace = 1) when the player hand was busted. The only issue with this is that every ace after that is now 1. So if the dealer has an ace, the ace is 1. If I attempt to change it back to 11 when I recalculate score at the end, the player score now has 10 extra score (adding the 10 to the ace value 1 to get 11). In addition to the append, I tried to add another dictionary, but I don't know how I would implement another dictionary. I have also tried to completely rewrite my program to have fewer classes.

I want the program to be able to change ace to 1 or 11 depending on the value. I have no idea what else to try. I can add more code if that would be beneficial to helping me understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way that a simple sum of numbers can capture the two possible values an ace can have. Instead you'll need to add some additional code to handle that aspect of blackjack.

One relatively easy way is to count the number of aces at the same time you're adding up the normal values of the cards. If you've busted, you can then adjust the score, in increments of 10, for each ace you've seen (10 because that's the difference between 11 and 1).

```
def get_score(self):
    score = 0
    aces = 0
    for c in cards:
        score += c.get_score()      # aces should return a value of 11
        if c.getrank() == "Ace":    # count aces
            aces += 1

    while aces > 0 and score > 21:  # try to avoid a bust by changing ace values from 11 to 1
        score -= 10                 # until the bust has ben avoided, or you're out of aces
        aces -= 1

    return score
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had tried this in the rewritten file that I made but did not have the if c.getrank() == 'Ace':